Python program: removing a file occasionally hangs the program. Need a way to timeout and keep going
I have a strange program where trying to remove a file in my python program will hang.  I have tried multiple methods to remove and they all hang.
The original code had just this command:
os.remove(file_to_remove)
I then replaced it with:
pathlib.Path(file_to_remove).unlink()
Finally, I also tried:
os.system('rm '+file_to_remove)
All three examples will eventually hang.
For background, the program creates and removes a LOT of small files based on data received from a websocket.  The program will run for a long time (many, many hours) without issue, and then out of the blue, it would hang on the remove-command.
Is there a way to set a timeout on the remove command so that if it hangs, the program will terminate that remove and retry?
When I see the remove-command hung, I can open another window to investigate.  If I try to cat the file that is being removed, I can see the contents without issue.  More interesting is that if I try to remove that file in the second terminal, the shell would say the file doesn't exist BUT IT WOULD UNHANG THE PYTHON.  That is the strangest thing.


Does this answer your question? Timeout on a function call

I would be grateful if someone can help me figure out why a simple 'rm' command would hang.  The OS is Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS with all the latest updates applied.
